# Fetching data from SQLite Database to Custom Card GridView( Library: Gabrielemariotti)

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

I am using this card library https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib. I have implemented custom cardgridcursoradapter and passed cursor in constructor of this class.
This is my custom cardgridcursoradapter class.

```
class CustCursorAdapter extends CardGridCursorAdapter{


    public CustCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
    }

    @Override
    protected Card getCardFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {

        MyCard card = new MyCard(super.getContext());

        return card;
    }

}
```

This is not displaying the Card Grid View. Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey my friend all you did is right, but as you said it is custom card grid view , you need to return a view with your card.
that means your adapter class need to override newview and bindview method. Like this.

```
class CustCursorAdapter extends CardGridCursorAdapter{


public CustCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
}

@Override
protected Card getCardFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {

    MyCard card = new MyCard(super.getContext());

    return card;
 }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_grid_item, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
        TextView password = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.password);
        Integer cursor_id= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        String cursor_name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name"));
        String cursor_username=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Username"));
        String cursor_password=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Password"));
        id.setText(String.valueOf(cursor_id));
        name.setText(cursor_name);
        username.setText(cursor_username);
        password.setText(cursor_password);
    }
}
```

Updated your adapter subclass like this.
(Remember to update the mycard class layout and java file.)

Comment: Let me check that out!!